# youtube iframe api setPlaybackRate not working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I've been using the youtube iframe api in a web app that I've been working on, and the *setPlaybackRate* method stopped working a few days ago. When I use *getAvailablePlaybackRates*, it returns the normal list of rates(0.25-2), but I'm unable to change it. Anyone else having issues with the function?

Comment: Please the iframe settings you have.

Comment: Make sure the argument for setPlaybackRate is a float value and not a string. We had the same issue.

Comment: @Foliovision it's of type number. Just out of curiosity, when was the last time you tested your app for playback rate? This is a relatively new problem, and I checked their demo in the documentation, and even that is broken.

Comment: @JoeKausits as weird as it sounds, I shouldn't trust too much in the Google demo. 
 See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54372981/4092887) - the setPlaybackRate works fine *(in my case)*...

Answer (score 0):

<s>This issue will be fixed soon. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130638003</s> Does not seem to happen.

But, as Foliovision puts it in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301800/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackrate-not-working/55749102#comment95541492_54301800), there is an easy fix. In your scripts, replace

```
player.setPlaybackRate(...);
```

with

```
player.setPlaybackRate(Number(...));
```

That is, make sure that what you are passing to this method is actually a number. `player.setPlaybackRate()` must have become picky about what it accepts as an argument. In my case, for example, it was the value of the selected option in a `<select>` element which ceased to work.